# Multihead Attention with for loop

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, nlp, transformer-model, attention-model

According to the Attention is All You Need paper

> Instead of performing a single attention function with dmodel-dimensional keys, values and queries, we found it beneficial to linearly project the queries, keys and values h times with different, learned linear projections to dk, dk and dv dimensions, respectively

What I understand is there should be `n_heads` *different* linear layers so that each learns a different projection. Thus, I implemented the logic as follows

```py
class Attention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embed_size=512, out_feat=64) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.embed_size = embed_size
        self.out_feat   = out_feat
        self.value_fc   = nn.Linear(embed_size, out_feat)
        self.query_fc   = nn.Linear(embed_size, out_feat)
        self.key_fc     = nn.Linear(embed_size, out_feat)

    def forward(self, value, key, query, mask=None) -> torch.Tensor:
        """
        value: torch.Tensor of shape (N, seq_len, embed_size)
        key: torch.Tensor of shape (N, seq_len, embed_size)
        query: torch.Tensor of shape (N, seq_len, embed_size)
        mask: torch.Tensor of shape (N, seq_len, seq_len)

        returns torch.Tensor of shape (N, seq_len, out_feat)
        """
        value = self.value_fc(value)  # N, seq_len, out_feat
        key = self.key_fc(key)
        query = self.query_fc(query)
        weights = torch.bmm(query, torch.transpose(key, 1, 2))
        weights /= math.sqrt(self.out_feat)  # N, query_len, key_len
        if mask != None:
            weights += mask
        weights = torch.softmax(weights, dim=2)
        return torch.bmm(weights, value)


class MultiHeadAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embed_size=512, n_heads=8) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        assert embed_size % n_heads == 0, "Input feat. dim must be div. by n_heads"

        self.embed_size = embed_size
        self.n_heads = n_heads
        self.out_feat = embed_size // n_heads
        self.attention_layers = nn.ModuleList(
            [Attention(self.embed_size, self.out_feat) for _ in range(self.n_heads)]
        )
        self.fc = nn.Linear(embed_size, embed_size)

    def forward(self, value, key, query, mask=None):
        values = [
            attention(value, key, query, mask) for attention in self.attention_layers
        ]
        return self.fc(torch.cat(values, dim=2))
```

However, all the (official) implementations I have seen use a single Attention layer but reshapes the keys, queries and values into `(batch_size, len, n_heads, d_model // n_heads)` (then they apply transpose before computing the attention weights). Although this is more efficient to compute, there is only one linear layer for each key, query and value rather than `n_heads` linear layers. I think this contradicts with what the paper says. I know this increases the amount of learnable parameters a lot but isn't this the correct way according to the paper?